# JavaScript confirm() boxes get value from both inputs

Tags: javascript, popup

I am wondering if there is a way to get the input values from two confirm() boxes in JavaScript. 
First the confirm() box pops up and ask for an "OK" or "Cancel" and then it pops up again asking for something else, again "Ok" or "Canel" I want to get the value from confirm() box 1 and confirm() box 2 and then write to the `<p>` with the Id "result".

for example if the user click "OK" on the question "Is is warm?" and click "OK" on the next confirm() box. I want to write: It's warm and it's raining.

This is what I have tried but it gives me only the value of the first confirm() box.

```
function weather() {
    var sunny,rainy;
    var sunny= confirm("Is it warm?");
    var rainy= confirm("Is it raining?");

    if (sunny== true){
        ans = "Summer!";

        if (rainy == true) {
            ans = "It's sunny and it's raining.";
        }
    } else if(sunny == false){
        ans = "It's not summer then.";

        if (rainy== false){
            ans = "At least it's not raining!";
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ans;
}
```

Comment: I put your code into jsfiddle and it is working just fine which makes sense because I saw no errors.  But, there are a few coding faux pas in your code.  Instead of `if (sunny == true)` just do `if (sunny)`.  Instead of your `else if` you can just do `else` since booleans only have two possible values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional `&&` operator to be more specific instead of nesting, this will also make it more clear.

You can additionally use a ternary operator `(condition) ? true : false` when only deciding between two options.

In the below I used it within the concatenation of a string.

```js
let a,b, str = '';
a = confirm("It is sunny.");
b = confirm("It is raining.");

if(a && b) str = "It's sunny and raining";
else if(!a && b || !b && a) str = "It's " + ((a) ? "sunny": "raining.");
else if(!a && !b) str = "Weather does not exist";

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `else if`, only an `else` block that contains another `if`

This:

```
if (sunny == true) {
    // sunny is true
} else if(sunny == false) {
    // ...
}
```

Actually means:

```
if (sunny == true){
    // sunny is true (actually "truthy": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)
} else {
    // sunny is NOT true, so sunny is definitely false (actually "falsy": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

    if (sunny == false) {
        // no need to test that, we already know that sunny is false
    }
}
```

Regarding the rest of your code here are some pointers:

```
function weather() {
  var sunny, rainy; // No need to declare those variables here since you redeclare on the next lines.
  var sunny = confirm("Is it warm?");
  var rainy = confirm("Is it raining?");
  if (sunny == true) {
    ans = "Summer!"; // missing var keyword here
    if (rainy == true) { // confirm returns a boolean, you should check for strict equality with ===
      ans = "It's sunny and it's raining.";
    }
    // You are not handling the case where sunny is true and rainy is false
  } else if (sunny == false) {
    ans = "It's not summer then.";
    if (rainy == false) { // confirm returns a boolean, you should check for strict equality with ===
      ans = "At least it's not raining!";
    }
    // You are not handling the case where sunny is false and rainy is true
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ans;
}
```

Finally, you probably just need  += ([concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment_2))

```js
function weather() {
  var sunny = confirm("Is it warm?");
  var rainy = confirm("Is it raining?");
  var ans;

  if (sunny === true) {
    ans = "Summer!";

    if (rainy === true) {
      ans += "It's sunny and it's raining.";
    }
  } else {
    ans = "It's not summer then.";

    if (rainy === false) {
      ans = "At least it's not raining!";
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ans;
}

weather();
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help guys! All the answers thought me something! :) 
I am a beginner at JavaScript and sorry for my bad coding...

I edited one of the answers and did it like this to cover all the different four scenarios:

```js
  function weather() {
    a = confirm("Is it sunny?");
    b = confirm("Is it raining?");
    
    if(a && b) str = "It's sunny and raining.";
    else if(!a && b) str = "It's not sunny and it's raining.";
    else if(a && !b) str = "It's sunny and it's not raining.";
    else if(!a && !b) str = "It's not sunny and it's not raining."; 
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
    }
```

```html
<button onClick="weather()">Test me!</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```